# why does my math quiz always print incorrect when the answer is correct

Tags: python, random

okay so im writing a code that randomly generates questions and lets the user answer but my problem is that even if the user gets the answer right it will always print incorrect

```
print ("what is your username")
name = input () .title()
print (name, "welcome")
import random
score=0
question=0
for i in range(10):
    ops = ["+", "-", "*"]
    num1 = random.randint (0,10)
    num2 = random.randint (0,10)
    oparator = random.choice(ops)
    Q=(str(num1)+(oparator)+(str(num2)))
    print (Q)
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)
    if oparator =='+':
        answer = (str(num1+num2))

    elif oparator =='-':
        answer = (str(num1-num2))

    else:
        oparator =='*'
        answer = (str(num1*num2))

    if guess == (Q):  
        print ("correct")
        score + 1

    else:
        print ("incorrect")
```

I honestly don't understand what is wrong.
any help would be greatly thanked 
p.s I know my codes a mess

Comment: what input did you give and what output you got

Comment: what do you mean? I am very new to python?

Comment: what was the input you gave to the program and what did you get from the program am I clear

Comment: You're comparing `guess` (What the person guessed the answer was) to `Q` which is a string containing the question. Perhaps it would be best to compare the guess to the answer, and make sure they're both either strings or integers.  You also don't want the `()` around the variable in the comparison.

Answer (score 3):

You need to compare guess with answer.

```
    print ("what is your username")
    name = input().title()
    print (name, "welcome")
    import random
    score=0
    question=0
    for i in range(10):
        ops = ["+", "-", "*"]
        num1 = random.randint (0,10)
        num2 = random.randint (0,10)
        oparator = random.choice(ops)
        Q=(str(num1)+(oparator)+(str(num2)))
        print (Q)
        guess = input()
        guess = int(guess)
        if oparator =='+':
            answer = int(str(num1+num2)) # Convert to int

        elif oparator =='-':
            answer = int(str(num1-num2))

        else:
            oparator =='*'
            answer = int(str(num1*num2))

        if guess == answer:  # Compare user's answer with actual answer
            print ("correct")
            score = score + 1 # Update the score

        else:
            print ("incorrect")
```