# how come my math code always says that my answer is incorrect?

Tags: python, math

i have just started programming and i am learning on how to make a math code that will tell the user if the answer is correct or not but the problem i am encountering is that even if i put the correct answer it prints my answer is incorrect and i have been trying to tackle the problem for several hours and cant find a solution.
this is my code in python:

```
print ("what is your username")
name = input () .title()
print (name, "welcome")
import random
score=0
question=0
for i in range(10):
 ops = ["+", "-", "*"]
 num1 = random.randint (0,10)
 num2 = random.randint (0,10)
 oparator = random.choice(ops)
 Q=(str(num1)+(oparator)+(str(num2)))
 print (Q)
 guess = int(input())

 if oparator =='+':
    answer = (int(num1-num2))

 elif oparator =='-':
    answer = (int(num1-num2))

 else:
        oparator =='*'
        answer = (int
                  (num1*num2))

 if guess == Q:  
    print ("correct")
    score + 1

 else:


    print ("incorrect")
```

im am really puzzled honestly, and help would be greatly appreciated
regards, kurt

Comment: Because you're subtracting when "operator" is `+`?

Comment: You've already got the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34221115/838992) when you asked the exact same question two hours ago.  You're comparing the `guess` with `Q` when you should compare it to `answer`.  In addition you have a typo in this version, where your `-` should be a `+` as pointed out in the above comment.  Please don't post the same question multiple times and do take the time to read the answers you get.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's the third time the exact same question has been posted by the same user in 2 hours and it's already answered in a previous version

Comment: Why do you think the other answer did not answer you?. If it did not answer your question then you could have commented on the answer. SO is a place where people try to help other don't be so rude.If it did not answer there might also be problem in your question so try to be more informative as possible.

Comment: We do know you are frustrated that you did not get the answer but that does not mean you can behave rude. **Be polite**

Comment: @Mc-wyldog Sorry if I came off a bit blunt.  I can see you're trying to improve your code and admire your objective stated in your first question, but the versions you are posting here are almost identical.  I'd recommend you have a look through the official python tutorial.  Some of the styles you are using (such as putting `()` round everything) are non-standard and might be adding to your confusion. Although the comments might feel blunt, the actions (closing as duplicate etc), just follow the rules of the site to help curate a repository of good, but specific, answers to specific problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing your `guess` (which is `int`) to the question `Q` (which is a `str`)

```
if guess == Q:
```

You want to compare

```
if guess == answer:
```

Also when you select `'+'` you have a mistake

```
if oparator =='+':
    answer = (int(num1-num2))
```

You want to do addition

```
if oparator =='+':
    answer = (int(num1+num2))
```

You also have indentation problems, among a variety of other issues.